# How to Deserialise the Jackson SNAKE CASE object mapper into CAMEL CASE data class model in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, jackson, jackson-databind

I have serialised the data class model "ProfileInfo" using

```
val jsonString = jacksonObjectMapper().setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE).writeValueAsString(profileInfo)
```

but when I deserialise the jsonString into data class model using

```
val profileInfo: ProfileInfo = jacksonObjectMapper().readValue<ProfileInfo>(jsonString)
```

only the fields without underscores receiving the value. other fields with underscores assigned as null. Could anybody help me about how to deserialise using Jackson object mapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each call to the `jacksonObjectMapper()` creates a new `ObjectMapper`, so either:

- use the same object mapper for both, serialization and deserialization

```kotlin
val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper().setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE)
val jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(profileInfo)
...
val profileInfo: ProfileInfo = mapper.readValue(jsonString)
```

- configure property naming strategy for deserialization the same way, you are doing it for serialization

```
val profileInfo: ProfileInfo = jacksonObjectMapper().setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE).readValue(jsonString)
```